# How to write special set notation by hand?

Tags: notation, online-resources

Does anyone know a good resource (preferably pictures) that illustrates a conventional way to write the special sets symbols, i.e. $\mathbb{N,Z,Q,R,C}$ etc., by hand?

Comment: In my experience, you kinda just make it up. I don't know of a 'conventional' way.

Comment: Just for the fun of it, [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nI8Y6.png) is blackboard bold in my terrible handwriting. (In addition to it, scanning something written by pen was probably not that good idea.)

Comment: @ Martin I like them!

Comment: @Martin : I write them exactly the same! Except that you sketched the $\mathbb C$ very bad. But I use the same technique :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think anybody duplicates mathblackboard very exactly. I'll describe what I do.

For $\mathbb{N}$, I draw the left vertical and a diagonal as normal, then I start over drawing another diagonal parallel to the first, then finish the right vertical. I do something similar for $\mathbb{Z}$.

For $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{H}$ I write an $R$ or $H$ as normal and then just double the left vertical.
For $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ I write a $Q$ or $C$ as normal, then add a vertical secant line close to the left side.

Comment: I mostly do the same, except for my $\mathbb{N}$ I double the left vertical (like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{H}$) instead of the diagonal.

Comment: @WillieWong I know I used to do that! I didn't realize I stopped. I think my method for doing $\mathbb{Z}$ probably became contagious and changed my $\mathbb{N}$. Anyway, I would like to endorse that as a completely standard thing, too.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Well this is the way I draw them anyway :)

Comment: terrible choice of background color, but I like it ;)

Comment: ahem! Doesn't it just jump out at you :)

Comment: Your $\mathbb{N}$ is “incorrect” in that a capital N in any serif font has the diagonal thickened, not the verticals. In fact, the rule (in Latin alphabet) is that negative slopes are thick, positive ones are thin. Verticals are sometimes thin, sometimes thick. Unique exception: Z. Just look in a newspaper at A, V, X, M, and N.

Comment: @Lubin: it's a matter of personal choice. The Latin rule is interesting though, never heard of that.

Answer (score 3):

Proper technique is to use two pens held like chopsticks.  You control the distance between the two lines by varying the angle at which you hold them just as you would with a fountain pen.

[image: two black pens held like chopsticks next to blackboard-bold letters N Z]

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia, W3.org (amongst many others) have lookup tables containing almost all  - if not all - Blackboard Bold / Double Strike "fontset" characters.

Each can be C&P into MS Office documents and other Windows 10 tools (MS Paint, Notepad, Sticky Notes etc),
Freely downloadable tools (e.g. Notepad++)
Social media platforms (Quora, Facebook, Reddit, etc.)
Software development IDE's: CodeBlocks, NetBeans, RStudio, Visual Studio, etc

No different from other ASCII character(s) that use U+XXXX (ALT+XXXX)

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold
2. https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/double-struck.html
3. https://blackboard.rutgers.edu/ https://www.ctan.org/pkg/blackboard
4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5ZbY.png

Many more.

⅀, ℿ, ℽ,...

, , , ...

ℤ, ℤ⁺,, , ℕ, ℚ, including lower case: , , , , ...

Comment: OP asked for tips on how to draw by hand, not to put into Word et cetera