# Can someone list all the hand-written notations of sets and vectors?

Tags: soft-question, notation

I often find it hard to accept my own handwriting when it comes to expressing sets (for instance, the set of real numbers, $\mathbb R$), and vectors (for instance, the vector $v=(v_1,v_2)^T$). I've seen $\mathbb R$ written something similar to IR, and $v$ with another line on either of its wings, but can someone list all of them so I can follow the example of them?

i.e if someone can write all 26 down each for capital and small case letters on a piece of paper, then take a picture of it, then upload it here, then that would be the best. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but the real numbers are handwritten as $\mathbb{R}$, and sometimes typeset as $\mathbf{R}$, but usually are typeset as $\mathbb{R}$ as well.

Comment: yes, but I'd like to be able to write down all of them on my notebook and be satisfied that I am using "acceptable" notation, since I don't have the knowledge to use LaTeX or other typeset language, and learn better when I write things down. I'm pretty sure no one wastes time to imitate the typeset R exactly when you are writing it on a piece of paper.

Comment: I was trying to say that there's only one handwritten notation that I know of for $\Bbb{R}$, which looks mostly the same as the typeset one. Namely draw a vertical line very close to the left side of an ordinary capital $\mathrm{R}$. (At least that's how I draw it).

Comment: What I am looking for is a guideline for all other capital letters, not just R. For example, how would a mathematician write C to express a set? Or f or g as a vector? Not on the computer but on paper or on the blackboard.

Comment: (not just mathematicians, but anyone who has studied math above calculus 3 (i.e. where vectors and sets start to appear)...)

Comment: Ah, I see, now I understand your question. I don't have a clear way to help with the blackboard bold capitals. (You could try google searching handwritten blackboard bold letters.) Mathematicians don't usually write vectors on the blackboard with fancy letters past calc 3. Usually it's just an ordinary roman lowercase letter, or if there is some special notation to denote a vector it's drawing an arrow over top of the letter.

Comment: Here you are for [blackboard bold handwriting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/152052/90543).

Comment: Be careful, you said "use C to express a set", but I would only use (a handwritten version of) $\mathbb C$ if the set is the set of the complex numbers. Otherwise I would use a regular $C$ or a C with a loop to simulate $\mathcal C$.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my best guess on handwritten blackboard bold capitals:

[image: handwritten blackboard bold capitals]

Note that I have written some of them for the first time right now, because they are rarely used in mathematics at all, like $\mathbb{S,U,X,Y}$, where I just guessed.

Blackboard bold lowercase letters don't exist as far as I know. For vectors we usually write $\mathbf a$, $\vec{a}$ or just $a$ in typesetting and stick to one of the two last variants in handwriting.